# 010 Editor template issue

Tags: templates, hex, binaryfiles

I'm trying to create template with "010 editor" and get the following issue.
The array size is not match with length variable.

[The array size is not match with length variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE6B6.png)

Template:

```
typedef struct {  
  int    length;
  char   value[length];
} MyString ;

typedef struct {    
  int   index;
  MyString    caption;
} MySection;

typedef struct {
  int    length;
  MySection    section[length];
} MySections;

struct FILE {
  MySections s;
}file;
```

Binary:

```
02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 1D 00 00 00 71 70 73 72
75 74 77 76 79 78 7B 7A 7D 7C 7F 7E 61 60 63 62
65 64 67 66 69 68 6B 6A 6D 02 00 00 00 21 00 00
00 61 60 63 62 65 64 67 66 69 68 6B 6A 6D 6C 6F
6E 71 70 73 72 75 74 77 76 79 78 7B 7A 7D 7C 7F
7E 41
```

pl. explain where i'm were wrong.

Comment: Solved. MySection    section[length]<optimize=false>;. [link](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/ArraysDuplicates.htm)